# value from same mysql table is integer with apache and string with nginx?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx, laravel-4

I use nginx on a vserver with laravel 4 and mariadb (10.0.15-MariaDB-1~trusty-log, mit PHP-Erweiterung MySQLi) and apache at home with laravel 4 too, and mariadb (5.5.5-10.0.15-MariaDB-log, mit PHP-Erweiterung MySQLi).

At home the OS is archlinux, and on the vserver it is ubuntu.

Both setups use the same database tables. the user table is identical. both user-id columns look like this: `id int(4) unsigned Auto-Inkrement` and both user-tables are `MyISAM    utf8_unicode_ci`

How could it be, that `var_dump(Auth::user()->id)` gives a string ("7") on the vserver and an integer (7) at home ?

I don't know where to search the problem. It must be something with apache and nginx, because today was my first try with nginx and the first time i recognized that behaviour. I did not change code. Just imported the database tables with adminer into the vserver.

#### edit

my hoster has replaced the driver **php5-mysql** with **php5-mysqlnd**. now the problem seems to be solved.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the creaky MyISAM engine unless you have a very compelling reason. Even then, the hosting environment isn't an issue. Are the versions of PHP identical?

Comment: home: `PHP 5.6.3 (cli) (built: Nov 13 2014 18:31:57)` and vserver: `PHP 5.6.3-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2014 19:38:33)` ..would you recommend the Aria engine instead?

Comment: I'm as baffled as you are. Is this a phenomenon that occurs on all tables, or just a few?

Comment: at least 3, but it seems as if it will be everywhere, i did not test all already

Comment: It's possible, if unlikely, that this is due to the way PHP was compiled even if the version numbers are the same. There's a lot of flags that affect how that comes together. You could try isolating variables like trying a different Ubuntu version, using MySQL instead of MariaDB and compiling from source yourself. It's pretty easy to try things like this if you use a virtual environment tool like [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/).

Comment: Ok. I changed 1 table to Aria, that did not change it.

Comment: do you use php-fpm on both? or do you use mod_php with apache?

Comment: I used apache locally, but now php-fpm / nginx on both. the difference int <> string is still there

Comment: I have a similar problem at the moment. It took me hours to realize why underscore.js methods were not working on production but working on localhost! Do you have idea on why changing the driver to `php5-mysqlnd` solves the issue and if I can achieve the same with `php5-mysql`?